# bash script using multiple arguments

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am writing a Bash Script that accepts command line arguments, but not only one at a time, but all of them at a time, using case statements.

Here is my code so far

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case "$1" in
      -n|--name)
          name="$2"
      ;;
      -s|--size)
          size="$2"
      ;;
      -l|--location)
          location="$2"
      ;;
    esac
done
```

This code only accepts one at a time, I need it to be able to specify as many as they want.

Comment: Look at the manual for `shift`. Also look at `getopts`, which is the right way to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `getopt` you could solve your task as follows:

```
OPTS=`getopt -o n:s:l: --long name:,size:,location: -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$OPTS"
```

This splits the original positional parameters into options (that take arguments, indicated by colons) and remaining arguments, both of which might be quoted. Afterwards the result of `getopt` is evaluated and `set -- $OPTS` sets the positional arguments `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ... to what `getopt` obtained. Afterwards we can just loop through the positional arguments (and stop as soon as we encounter `--` which separates options from the remaining arguments to the script).

```
while true
do
  case "$1" in
    -n|--name)
      name="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    -s|--size)
      size="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    -l|--location)
      location="$2"
      shift 2
      ;;
    --)
      shift
      break
      ;;
     *)
      echo "Internal error!"
      exit 1
  esac
done

echo -e "name: $name\nsize: $size\nlocation: $location"
```